Error messages showed up during open a input file with pwgui software
It keep shows following message everytime i try to open a Quantum Espresso input file with PWgui software (QEs gui).
==================================================
PWgui version :   7.2
-

PWGUI       : /opt/local/bin/qe-7.3/GUI/PWgui/
GUIB engine : /opt/local/bin/qe-7.3/GUI/PWgui/lib/Guib-1.0

member function "::guib::moduleObj::makeEmbedGUI" is not defined and cannot be autoloaded
while executing
"$obj makeEmbedGUI \[expr {$containerWidget != "." ? $containerWidget : "" }\]"
(procedure "::guib::embedGUI" line 6)
invoked from within
"::guib::embedGUI $moduleFile $wid"
(object "::gUI0" method "::guib::GUI::\_newInput" body line 56)
invoked from within
"\_newInput $moduleIdent $moduleName $moduleFile"
(object "::gUI0" method "::guib::GUI::openInput" body line 11)
invoked from within
"$gui openInput $moduleIdent $moduleName $moduleFile $inputFile"
(file "/opt/local/bin/qe-7.3/GUI/PWgui//pwgui.tcl" line 10)
invoked from within
"source $env(PWGUI)/pwgui.tcl"
(file "/opt/local/bin/qe-7.3/GUI/PWgui/pwgui" line 41)

Here I have insert the pwgui.tcl file which is causing these error as my understanding.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#  PROGRAM: PWgui
#  PURPOSE: A GUI input builder for PWscf
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Anton Kokalj
#  Jozef Stefan Institute, Ljubljana, Slovenia
#  Email: tone.kokalj@ijs.si
# ======================================================================
#  Copyright (c) 2003--2023 Anton Kokalj
# ======================================================================
#
#
# This file is distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public
# License. See the file COPYING' in the root directory of the present
# distribution, or http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.txt .
#
# 
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
# EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
# MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
# NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL ANTON KOKALJ BE LIABLE FOR ANY
# CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
# TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
# SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#


# PWgui version

set fid [open $env(PWGUI)/VERSION]
set ver [read -nonewline $fid]
close $fid


# make a list of which QE programs are supported

foreach item [glob -nocomplain [file join $env(PWGUI) modules *]] {
    if { [file isdirectory $item] } {
        set prog [file tail $item]
        if { $prog == "atomic" } {
            append progs "          [format {%-9s  or  %-9s} ld1.x atomic]\n"
        } else {
            append progs "          [format {%-9s  or  %-9s} $prog.x $prog]\n"
        }
        lappend prog_l [file rootname $prog]
    }
}

# usage

set usage [subst -nocommands {
    Usage:  pwgui [-h] |  [-r program inputFile] [-o program inputFile]

    Description of options:

    -h
    -?
    --help
          Print this usage message.

    -r  program  inputFile
    --reformat  program  inputFile
          Read the "inputFile" of the QE's "program" (e.g. pw.x, pp.x, ...),
          check its syntax for correctness, and print it nicely formatted.

    -o  program  inputFile
    --open  program  inputFile
          Open the "inputFile" of the QE's "program" (e.g. pw.x, pp.x, ...)
          in PWgui.

    Valid values for "program" are:

$progs
}]

set o_usage {
    Incorrect usage of $opt option, must be:
    
    pwgui $opt program inputFile
}


# parse command-line options

set reformat 0
set open     0

if { $argc > 0 } {
    set opt [lindex $argv 0]
    switch -glob -- $opt {
        -h - --help - -\\? {
            puts $usage
            exit 0
        }
        -r* - --ref* {
            # -r | --reformat
            if { $argc != 3 } { puts [subst $o_usage]; exit 1 }
            set reformat 1
        }
        -o* - --open {
            # -o | --open
            if { $argc != 3 } { puts [subst $o_usage]; exit 1 }
            set open 1
        }
        default {
            puts "\n    Incorrect option \"$opt\", aborting...\n$usage"
            exit 1
        }
    }

    set module    [file rootname [lindex $argv 1]]
    set inputFile [lindex $argv 2]
    if { ! [file exists $inputFile] } {
        puts "
   File \"$inputFile\" does not exist.\n"  
        exit 1
    }
    if { $module == "ld1" || $module == "atomic" } {
        set module      atomic
        set moduleIdent ld
        set moduleName  LD1.X
    } else {
        set moduleIdent $module
        set moduleName  [string toupper $module].X
    }
    set moduleFile [file join $env(PWGUI) modules $module $module.tcl]

    # check for valid module    
    
    if { [lsearch $prog_l $module] < 0 } {
        puts "[subst $o_usage]
    where program must be one of:
    
       [join $prog_l {, }]\n"
        exit 1
    }
}


if { [info exists env(PWGUI)] } {    
    set guib_dir [glob -nocomplain -directory [file join $env(PWGUI) lib] Guib-*]
    if { $guib_dir != "" } {
    set env(GUIB) $guib_dir
    } else {
        set guib_dir [file normalize [file join $env(PWGUI) .. Guib]]
    if { [file isdirectory $guib_dir] } {
            # we arrive here, if we are using PWgui inside the QE
            set env(GUIB) $guib_dir
        }
    }

    if { [info exists env(GUIB)] } {
    lappend auto_path $env(GUIB)
    } else {
        puts "
 Guib engine was not found. 
 You may consider to defined GUIB enviromental variable that points to Guib engine.

 Aborting.
"
        exit 1
    }

    if { ! $reformat } {
        puts "
 ==================================================
  PWgui version :   $ver
 --------------------------------------------------

 PWGUI       : $env(PWGUI)
 GUIB engine : $env(GUIB)\n"
    }
    
} else {
    puts stderr " "
    puts stderr " Please define the PWGUI enviromental variable !!!"
    puts stderr " PWGUI should point to the PWgui root directory."
    puts stderr " "
    exit 1
}


#
# all initialization stuff should go into init.tcl
#
source [file join $env(PWGUI) init.tcl]

wm withdraw .

if { ! $reformat } {
    #
    # open a GUI main window
    #
    bind . <Destroy> ::guib::exitApp
    source [file join $env(PWGUI) src pwscf.itcl]

    if { $open } {
        # open the specified input file
        $gui openInput $moduleIdent $moduleName $moduleFile $inputFile
    }
} else {
    #
    # only reformat the specified input file
    #
    set ::tclu::DEBUG 0
    set ::tclu::DEBUG_FILE 0
    option readfile [file join $::guib::library guib.theme] startupFile

    namespace eval ::guib  {
        set moduleObj [embedGUI $::moduleFile .]
        $moduleObj openFile $::inputFile
        $moduleObj print 1
    }
    exit 0
}


My personal thoughts on this is, somehow there might be compatibility issues with guib and pwgui softwares. I am not familiar with this programming language and not a expert in this. So I am grateful to anyone who can go through the code and see what went wrong.

Unfortunately, the source file that you showed us doesn't appear to be involved; nothing in it seems to be on the error trace. The error trace says that the makeEmbedGUI method is missing, but that's not a standard Tcl feature so I'm guessing it must be part of the app that is missing somehow. Why that is so is completely mysterious to me..

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@DonalFellows As you think what sould be my next move on this matter?
